# File Dump failed when launching a Python Process from Node.js

Tags: python, node.js, spawn, joblib

I have a node.js app that spawns a Python child process. This Python process trains a ML model, then tries to save the model to a local directory.

Within the python source file:

```
import joblib


classifier = LinearSVC(max_iter=maxIter, dual=dual, C=C)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
joblib.dump(classifier, "LinearSVC_"+timeStamp+".pkl")
```

From node.js, this module is used:

```
const {spawn} = require('child_process');
```

The python process (if this process is spawned from node.js) always fails on the dump line. However, when I invoke this Python script from the command line, there are no errors, and the dump operation works as expected.
Why does the spawned process fail, and is there a way to resolve this ?

Comment: What error are you getting when you run it from node? If you are able to run the python correctly from the cli, I would expect the interface between node and python to be the issue.

Comment: I was able to print(e); the exception and its details from Python back to Node.js. The exception's details led me to believe that the issue was the file name I gave to the dumped file is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was, the name of the output dump file was invalid. The timestamp string (which was part of the dump file's intended name) had spaces and colons in it.

```
timeStamp --> "Sat Mar 20 2021 23:29:28 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"
joblib.dump(classifier, "LinearSVC_"+timeStamp+".pkl")
```

My resolution: simply reformat the timestamp string. The .pkl file is successfully created afterwards.